# Multiply each number in an array by n - java

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

Is there a way which i can multiply each number that is stored within an array by n.

For example,

```
public static int [] intArray = new int [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

n = 3

it should output: 3, 6, 9, 12,15,18, 21.

I'm not sure how to do this, help would be appreciated!

Comment: Probably some kind of array map function. Most languages have a built-in version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the simplest solution.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=3;
        int [] intArray = new int [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
       for(int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(intArray[i]*n);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Java 8 way, for a given n:

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).map(i -> i * n).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

The functional approach would be to use Stream.map:

```
    int [] intArray = new int [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int n = 3;
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(intArray).map(i -> i * n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be super small,

```
int n = 3;
int[] intArray = blah;

for (int i : intArray) {
    System.out.println(""+i*n); //The "" is to make the number i*n a string
}
```

Comment: The `""+` is not needed. `println` can also output numbers.

Comment: Also, use methods like `Integer.toString()` instead of empty concatenation when you want to do such conversions.